# Grails equivalent of Djangos list_filter, search_fields and date_hierarchy

Tags: grails

In Django you can specify in the controller (admin.py) what fields of a model you want to use for filtering and searching through the records of a model when you are viewing the webpage for it. E.g.

...

class BooksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
  ...
  list_filter = ('author', 'pub_date', 'publisher',)
  search_fields = ('author', 'title', 'publisher',)
  date_hierarchy = 'pub_date'
```

admin.site.register(Book, BooksAdmin)

I know Django's "search_fields = ('author', 'title', 'publisher',)" can be replaced by Grails' searchable plugin and specifying searchable = true in the BooKController but what's the equivalent or replacement in Grails for Django's "list_filter" and "date_hierarchy?"

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like not too much people there knows both grails and django, so maybe it will be better to explain more detailed what it means 'list_filter' and 'date_hierarchy'?

Answer (score 0):

- [Filter Pane](http://www.grails.org/plugin/filterpane) seems to do what `list_filter` seems to do :D There was a [filter](http://www.grails.org/plugin/filter) plugin, but it hasn't been updated since 2009.
- If I get `date_hierarchy` idea right, [there are](http://www.grails.org/plugin/joda-time) various [date datatypes](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html), though one has to register those type editors oneself - standard `g:datePicker` editor is pretty poor.

Comment: Thanks Victor. The filter plugin seems to be close to what I was looking for. It accomplishes the use of both the 'list_filter' and 'date_hierarchy.' Thank you again.